# HTTP vs. SAP adapters in MFP 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, jco, sap-gateway, mobilefirst-studio

Trying to use the Service Discovery feature of MobileFirst Platform Studio  7.1.0.00-20160323-1606.

The adapter.xml file that gets generated is for an HTTP adapter, not an SAP adapter.

`<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration" 
            xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    name="SAPGWAdapter1">`

That also creates the connectionPolicy tag as `<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">`

This doesn't allow me to add properties that were included with the `xsi:type="nwgateway:NWGatewayHTTPConnectionPolicyType"` type definition, like `<serviceRootURL>` and the `<serverIdentity>` nodes.

Can I change the adapter type back to SAP, or is HTTP the standard now?  If it is, how do I pass in the serverIdentity properties?  Trying to test the adapter against a live SAP instance is giving me "Unauthorized" errors (at least, I think that's what it says.  It's in German...)

-Paul Horan-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still offer SAP adapters. Use whichever adapter best fits the task.

Create a new Adapter, if you are using the eclipse plugin then right click on adapters > new > MobileFirst Adapter

Under adapter type you have two options

- SAP Netweaver Gateway Adapter
- SAP JCo Adapter

[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_sap_adapters.html?lang=en) is our user documentation on SAP adapters

Comment: OK - this was totally my mistake...   I was getting Authorization Failed errors correctly, as I was passing the wrong parameter value for "sap-client".  
Once I corrected that mistake, the HTTP adapter works just fine.